# Comparing two hex values using if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, hex

I've written an `if` statement comparing two `hex` value,but this `if` says values are `!=` even when they are `==` ! . I can see that they are equal as I print their values with `printf`!!!

```
uint64_t sys_call_table_offset = 0xc033e7f4;
uint64_t sys_call_func_ptr;
uint64_t syscall_func_ptr[15] = {  0xc0107c30,//0->2
                                   0xc0152ea0,//1->3
                                   0xc0152fe0,//2->4
                                   0xc0152220,//3->5
                                   0xc0107d40,//4->11
                                   0xc0151750,//5->12
                                   0xc0132300,//6->23
                                   0xc012dae0,//7->24
                                   0xc01303a0,//8->37
                                   0xc0165230,//9->54
                                   0xc02086d0,//10->102
                                   0xc0107c80,//11->120
                                   0xc0165cb0,//12->141
                                   0xc0124e50,//13->167
                                   0xc0165e70,//14->220 
                                 };
int sys_num[15]={2,3,4,5,11,12,23,24,37,54,102,120,141,167,220};
int i;
for(i = 0 ; i<15 ; i++)
 {
  vmi_read_32_va(vmi,sys_call_table_offset + (sys_num[i] * 0x4) , 0, &sys_call_func_ptr);
  printf("sys_call_ptr = %x",sys_call_func_ptr);
  printf("      sys_call_ptr = %x    i=%d \n",syscall_func_ptr[i],i);
  if(syscall_func_ptr[i]!= sys_call_func_ptr)
     printf("Detected hooked system call!\n");
 }
```

this is output of printf:

```
sys_call_ptr = c0107c30    sys_call_ptr = c0107c30    i=0 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c0152ea0    sys_call_ptr = c0152ea0    i=1 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c0152fe0    sys_call_ptr = c0152fe0    i=2 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c0152220    sys_call_ptr = c0152220    i=3 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c0107d40    sys_call_ptr = c0107d40    i=4 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c0151750    sys_call_ptr = c0151750    i=5 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c0135b20    sys_call_ptr = c0132300    i=6 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c0135f30    sys_call_ptr = c012dae0    i=7 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c01303a0    sys_call_ptr = c01303a0    i=8 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c0165230    sys_call_ptr = c0165230    i=9 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c0209580    sys_call_ptr = c02086d0    i=10 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c0107c80    sys_call_ptr = c0107c80    i=11 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c0165cb0    sys_call_ptr = c0165cb0    i=12 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c0124e50    sys_call_ptr = c0124e50    i=13 
Detected hooked system call!
sys_call_ptr = c0165e70    sys_call_ptr = c0165e70    i=14 
Detected hooked system call!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `"%lx"` to see the whole 64 bit values?
Does `vmi_read_32_va` fill the entire 64 bits of the passed `&sys_call_func_ptr`?
If not, then you need to account for the 32 junk bits.

Answer (score 2):

[`vmi_read_32_va`](http://libvmi.gtisc.gatech.edu/libvmi_8h.html#adf710b1c7461e50d3201fd39c0eefe98) expects a pointer to `uint32_t` as last argument, but you give it a pointer to `uint64_t`, which is uninitialized, so it only fills 32 bits of it, the rest have an undefined value (which is not 0 in most of the cases).

You are printing only the 4 LSB ( `%x` ) but comparing the full 8 bytes of the 64bit numbers.
If you will print the whole number (`%llx`) you will see the difference.

Comment: I changed type of variables to `uint32_t` and now it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If using types from `inttypes.h` (like `uint64_t`) the straight forward approach to print them would be to use the corresponing macros defined in the same header.

So to print an `uint64_t`  use `PRIX64`.

```
uint64_t ui64 = (uint64_t)0xffff*0x10000*0x10000;

...

printf("0x"PRIX64" 0x"PRIX64"\n", ui64, ui64);
```

would print:

```
0xFFFF00000000 0xFFFF00000000
```

on a 32 bit machine as well as on 64bit machine.

As per your code it would look like this:

```
printf("sys_call_ptr = "PRIX64, sys_call_func_ptr);
```